# Programmatically use a copy of existing on-page customized control

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

On one page i use a web-control (do not pay attention that this is not standart webcontrol, there's no difference for that question):

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" id="rcbAssocClient" Width="400px"
    MarkFirstMatch="true" EnableLoadOnDemand="true"
    HighlightTemplatedItems="true"
    onitemsrequested="rcbAssocClient_ItemsRequested">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <ul>
         <li class="col1">FirstName</li>
         <li class="col2">LastName</li>
         <li class="col3">BirthDate</li>
    </ul>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
        <ul>
             <li class="col1">
                  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %></li>
             <li class="col2">
                  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName") %></li>
             <li class="col3">
                  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BirthDate", "{0:d/M/yyyy}")%></li>
        </ul>
   </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

How can i save this template to create the same control on *another* page *programmatically* like that:

```
MyRadComboBox cb = new MyRadComboBox();
```

without rewriting item template and so on.

Thanks in advance for Your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your template in a separated file ascx and load with method
[LoadTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadtemplate(v=vs.100).aspx)

I hope to be helpful

Comment: Thanks! Probably an user control must be the most accurate realization of that... I'll update the thread when done